# Organizing games launchers

Tags: launcher, unity-dash, games

On my kids account on the computer I kept installing a game and I locking them to the launcher on the left. After a while, the launcher got pretty swamped.

My kids are not proficient enough to search for their games on the "Dash" and also they don't always are looking for a specific game, some times they just want to browse the installed games...

What can I do to so that if they want to play a game they will be presented with the list of installed games?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very simple solution would be creating links to the applications on the desktop and having the children open this folder to access the list.

Simple Drag'n'Drop from the Dash to the Desktop and forming a folder there should work.

Edit: As for using the launcher, a bookmark on nautilus, or having the aforementioned folder prominently in `~/` would lead to *Launcher -> Home Folder -> Game Folder*, which should be straightforward enough, as well, in most cases.

Comment: Thanks! Great! also after dragging and dropping the game's icon,  right click it -> properties -> permissions tab -> set checkbox allow execution. This will use the specific game's icon.